# onClick - change style to multiple DOM nodes

Tags: html, dom

I have a number of paragraphs and headings. I want to be able to change the paragraphs `<p>` using and event but only the top paragraph changes. The following is an example

```
<p id= "id1"> text </p>
<h3> heading </h3>
<p id= "id1"> more text </p>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.color = 'red'">Click Me!</button>
```

When I do this only the top para changes. Is it possible to get all paras to change. Also, how would I use an image rather than a button?
Tks

Comment: You can't repeat IDs. Both of your `<p>` elements have the ID of `id1`.

Comment: And ID is meant to *ID*entify an element. You can't have duplicate IDs, just like you can't have duplicate car plates.

Comment: `id` is unique and what you want to do requires more code. you need to iterate all the nodes using `querySelectorAll("p")`

Comment: anyway you should probably do it with a mix of JS and CSS, apply a class through JS and then style it in CSS

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you are targeting one element via its ID. You need to query for all paragraphs and apply the styles to each.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
// Not all browsers have `forEach` on NodeLists, convert to array
const paragraphs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('p'));
const image = document.querySelector('img');

button.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
image.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);

function clickHandler(e) {
  // Loop through all paragraph tags
  paragraphs.forEach(p => p.style.color = 'red');
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<button>Change colors</button>
<img src="https://www.placecage.com/200/100">
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for that. I'm trying now to change the font size by using paragraphs.forEach(p => p.style.font-size = '20px'); but its not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd suggest checking out a few tutorials to get up to speed on the basics. In this case it's `fontSize` not `font-size`. MDN is a great website for all the ins and outs of JavaScript.